# If $P(A \cup B) = 1$ then does $B = A^c$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let A and B be two arbitrary events in a sample space S. Prove the following or provide a counterexample:

If $P(A \cup B) =  1$ then $B = A^c$

---

This is my original answer:

Since both $A, B \in S$ and $P(A \cup B) = 1$ then by definition $A \cup B = S$:
$$S = A \cup B$$
$$S \cap B^c = A \cup B \cap B^c$$
$$B^c = A$$
$$B = A^c$$

---

But I now realize that $P(A \cup B) = 1$ does not necessarily imply that $A \cup B = S$ so my proof doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the space of outcomes $\{a, b\}$ with probability $P(a) = 1$ and $P(b) = 0$.

Take the event $A = \{a\}$. Then $P(A) = 1$.

Take any event $B$ of the same space, then $P(A \cup B) = 1$.

Let $B = A$, then you have a counter example, because $B \neq A^c$

Comment: This would work with A = {a} and B = {a, b}, correct? If I'm understanding your last line correctly, you are saying that A = {a} and B = {a} since A = B. I don't quite understand the significance of that since it would just be (A U A)

Comment: @dude987321 Yes, Here in Pythalex's example we have $1 = P(A) \leq P(A\cup B) \leq 1$ hence $P(A\cup B) = 1$ regardless of the choice of $B$, in particular when $B=A$.  Nothing in the problem required $A$ to be distinct from $B$.

Comment: @dude987321 Your proof would mean that it works for every B, even B = A. So the counter example is precisely to note that $A = A^c$ isn't true for any arbitrary events.

Answer (score 6):

Take any even $A$ such that $P(A)=1$. Take $B=A$. Then

1. What is $P(A\cup B)$?
2. Is $B=A^c$?

Answer (score 3):

For one particularly straightforward counterexample, consider $A=B=S$.  We have here $P(A\cup B) = P(S\cup S) =P(S) = 1$ despite $B\neq A^c = \emptyset$

For a more exotic counterexample, let $N$ be a non-empty null set (*an event who occurs with probability zero but is still technically in the sample space*) who shares some element(s) with $A^c$ and let $B = A^c\setminus N$.

You make two major mistakes in your attempt.  The first is as you noted $P(A\cup B) = 1$ does not imply that $A\cup B = S$ due to the existence of null sets.

Your second major mistake is in going from $S=A\cup B$ to $S\cap B^c = A\cup B\cap B^c$.  You left off parentheses and evaluated as though parentheses were on the right as though $A\cup (B\cap B^c)$ leading to $A\cup (\emptyset)$ to $A$.  Rather, $S = (A\cup B)$ implies $S\cap B^c = (A\cup B)\cap B^c$ which leads to $B^c = A\cap B^c$.

Having corrected these two mistakes, we should have arrived at the conclusion that $P(A\cup B) = 1$ implies that $B^c$ is a subset of $A$ up to the difference of a nullset.  That is to say, $B^c\setminus A$ is a nullset.

For explicit example, consider the space $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ where $P(\{1\})=P(\{2\})=P(\{3\})=P(\{4\})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P(\{0\})=0$.  Letting $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4\}$ we do indeed have $P(A\cup B) = P(\{1,2,3,4\}) = 1$ and $B^c = \{0,1\}$ which although is not a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ it does differ from a subset of $A$, namely $\{1\}$ by only a null-set.

Comment: A downvote explanation would be appreciated.  My answer attempts to address the mistakes made by the OP which I believe to be the more important thing to focus on here and isn't addressed in the other answers.